# Cannot get input string data

Tags: c++

I want to get input string from a user, to avoid spaces i used gets_s and it outputs this error:

[image]

```
 char str[] = "", symb;
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Please enter String: ";
    gets_s(str);
    cout << "Which character you want to find: ";
    symb = getchar();

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i]==symb)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Character: " << symb << " found " << count << " times.";
```

Comment: `gets_s(str);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: This is an artifact of using character arrays.  Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Do not use `char[]`, `getchar` and `gets_s`. Use `std::string`, `std::getline` and `std::cin`.

Comment: `char str[] = "", symb;`? Really? ...whatever material you are using to learn C++, please throw it away and burn it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ the common string input idiom involves `std::string` and `std::getline`:

```
string text;
cout << "Please enter String: ";
getline(cin, text);
```

The `string` includes search methods, such as `find`.